# Multiply with lambda in list comprehension

Tags: lambda, list-comprehension

guys i will be really thankfull if you help me out, I'm extracting digits from a string, and after that I need to multiply all digits(example: [5, 6, 7, 8] = 5 * 6 * 7 * 8)
I was wondering is there a way to do it with lambda function in list comprehension?
Like first transforming them into integers and than multiplying them?

Below you can see and example the way i do it with for loop.

```py
piece_of_string = "abc23a@cvs21"
extracted_digits = [int(x) for x in re.findall("\d", piece_of_string)]


multiplied_digits = 1
for digit in extracted_digits:
    multiplied_digits *= digit
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need lambda in such simple case:

```
import math
numbers = [int(item) for item in piece_of_string if item.isnumeric()]
product = math.prod(numbers)
```